# Remove file ABC if file DEF exists, ask for a one line solution

Tags: bash, shell

Is there a one-line solution to remove file ABC if file DEF exists in the same folder? Using bash shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
[[ -f "DEF" ]] && rm "ABC"
```

- `-f "def"` will make sure that file DEF exists
- `&&` will execute `rm` command if file check is successful

Comment: +1 fast and furious, or should I say, you are fast and I am furious! `:P`

Answer (score 1):

To do this in multiple folders:

```
find /root/location -type f -name "ABC" -execdir rm DEF \;
```